# fatal: ssh variant 'simple' does not support setting port

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit

When I clone a remote GitLab project, I get the following error:

```
error fatal: ssh variant 'simple' does not support setting port
```

I tried to re-install TortoiseGit, but this did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The internal behavior of Git (>=2.16.0) for SSH tool detection changed and `TortoiseGitPlink` is not detected any more as `ssh` or `plink` compatible.

This only affects if the SSH URL contains a port or you have configured Git to use the Protocol version 2. For now, you need to set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_VARIANT` to `ssh` or configure it in Git settings using `git config --global ssh.variant ssh`.

In the next version of TortoiseGit 2.5.7 this will be done automatically when TortoiseGitPLink is invoked by TortoiseGit (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3139). If you use `TortoiseGitPLink` from CLI the setting is still needed).

**Update (TLDR)**:

- Update TortoiseGit to the latest stable version: https://tortoisegit.org/download/
- I f you use `TortoiseGitPLink` from Git CLI also issue `git config --global ssh.variant ssh` on CLI or set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_VARIANT` to `ssh`.

Comment: run in git bash `git config --global ssh.variant ssh`

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you.

Answer (score 29):

if you are using Windows version of git, try this:

`git config --global ssh.variant ssh`

This is a better option for those who don't want to clutter the environment variables a lot.

Comment: Why...? How...?

Answer (score 16):

Set environment variable `GIT_SSH_VARIANT` to `ssh`. This will solve the problem.

```
export GIT_SSH_VARIANT=ssh
```

Comment: Works on Windows as well using:
set GIT_SSH_VARIANT=ssh